# Using pexpect and interactive commands

Tags: python, puppet, pexpect

I'm trying to write a script that logs into a remote server, starts a process, outputs the log file to the console (stdout), and then asks you if you want to continue based on what you saw in the log file. Basically as a rough example:

```
import pexpect

server = raw_input('Server to connect to: ')
LoginPrompt = '[$#]'

start_login = pexpect.spawn('ssh %s')%(server))
start_login.expect(LoginPrompt)
start_login.sendline('./bin/service.sh start')
start_login.expect(LoginPrompt, timeout=10)
start_login.sendline('more /logs/services/nohup.service.out')
# I want it to drop to an interactive session here for the more
service_status = raw_input('Do you want to continue? ')
etc..
```

My problem currently is two-fold. I really want the 'more' command to be interactive, which I definitely have not gotten working. I decided as a hack to just 'cat' the output, but even doing that and using print start_login.after, I get no output. I can put a start_login.interact there, but that's not really giving me the function I want either, and I still don't get the output from the more/cat.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what is the specific issue with `start_login.interact()`?

Comment: Even putting a start_login.interact() I don't get output from the previous more/cat command. Also, when I have used it I have to 'exit' the interactive shell for the script to continue, which isn't ideal.

Comment: The point of `.interact()` is to be able to interact with the `more` command. If you need to download a file via ssh; it is another question.

Comment: I think you probably want to `cat` the file, then `.expect(LoginPrompt)` again to read that content, then access `.before`. However, because the prompt is really generic, if the file contains `$` or `#`, it will only read up to that. So you probably want to change the prompt to something more distinct first. If you use [pexpect.pxssh](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/pxssh.html), it takes care of that for you.